# Scale PostScript Image via GhostScript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, image-scaling

I have a postscript image, which I wanted to scale down to 84x84 pixels.

I tried the following line ( and different ones, but this one is the furthest I got ):

```
gs -sOutputFile=somefile.bmp -sDEVICE=bmpgray -q -g84x84 -dDEVICEWIDTH=84 -dDEVICEHEIGHT=84 -dPDFFitPage frames/frame_00000055.ps
```

This did not achieve what I wanted (all it does is showing a white image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with that command line. There is no command line switch -dDEVICEHEIGHT or -dDEVICEWIDTH, the relevant switches are -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS and -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS. You should never attempt to set the media size in two different ways anwyay, it will only lead to problems of some kind. You've specified -dPDFFitPage, but you appear to have supplied a PostScript program as the input.

Unsurprisingly, the PDFFitPage parameter does not scale PostScript.

When you are having problems of any kind, its best **not** to mute the application using -q (for quiet), in case its trying to tell you something.

Try using -dFitPage instead of -dPDFFitPage. If that still doesn't work, then I'll need to see your PostScript program.

84x84 pixels is tiny, its entirely conceivable that the result of downscaling a PostScript program could result in no pixel centers being touched, in which case the output will indeed be blank.

Comment: My dear Lord, hail the ghostscript master! Thank you a lot, this did indeed solve a lot. Now if you could tell me how I can make the image stretch to fill out the page instead of being scaled to fit, I would be send you my horses to bring you gold and garments! (Figuratively)

Comment: Well you can change the page size, it'll scale to fit the page. If you want to scale non-isomorphically or something, then you need to use PostScript. The difficulty there is that you need to know the size. If you use the Ghostscript bbox device then it will print a BoundingBox for the page. You can use that to construct arguments to the scale and translate operators and send that PostScript before the input. A more complex solution could use a BeginPage  routine to modify the CTM at the beginning of the page, such a routine could be supplied with data for multiple pages.